# Is it possible to draw the content out of the canvas in fabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I was try to make a navigator function (like navigator in photoshop) in my `fabricjs` project:

[image]

The left bottom is the navator, and the center is the all content, dark grey area is my workspace area, and the light grey is the canvas area, i draw all contents (exclude the navigator) in that light grey canvas area.

The snapshot i draw on the navigator is the contents in dark grey area. I use `canvas.toDataUrl({left:xxx,top:xxx,width:xxx,height:xxx})` to crop the dark area from the big canvas

[image]

As i zoom in and change the viewport little down and right, the upper and left area of the workspace (dark grey area) is placed out of the canvas.

As you can see, the snapshot capture nothing but black in the beyond area, I want the thumb is still the content of the dark area, even they are moved over the canvas

Is that possible to capture them all?

Comment: you should add some information on how your navigator works.

Comment: sorry for my pool description.
i re-edit my post,please check again,thanks

Comment: i m developing something similar, i have no answer rigth now, but the concept idea is to ise two separate canvas for that.